# python - global name <function> is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How do you use a method from the same class in this case? I am trying to make a tkinter scale that will update every time it is changed. How do I collect this value?

This is a snippet of the code

For example,

```
class Humidity(Page):

   humidityValue = 0

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      container = tk.Frame(self)
      container.pack(side="top", expand =True, fill = "both")

      humidityScale = tk.Scale(container, from_=0, to=60, tickinterval=10, width= 30,
                             orient="horizontal", borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness= 0, length=800, command=set_humidity)
      humidityLabel = tk.Label(container, text="Humidity(%)" , fg='White')
      humidityScale.pack(side="top")                            
      humidityScale.set(25)                                    #Sets humidity values to 25%
      humidityLabel.pack(side="bottom")
      humidityValue = humidityScale.get()

   def get_humidity(self):
      print self.humidityValue

   def set_humidity(val):
      humidityValue = val
```

Will return an error saying : global name 'set_humidity' is not defined

Comment: Python != Java. Instance variables *require explicite reference*, in a method, this is through *`self`*, although note, the actual name `self` is a convention. You could use whatever you want, but it is always the *first argument to the method*.You should familiarize yourself with some Python OOP tutorials. Starting with the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) would be good. Also note, it is not customary to use getters and setters in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, I was definitley thinking about it like it was Java, the distinction is now clear.

Comment: Note also that you should not put `humidityValue = 0` at the class level unless you *actually want to create a static class variable*. However, since in your constructor you're going to assign to `self.humidityValue = <something>` you will *shadow the class-level variable with an instance variable*, making it pointless. This can also lead to subtle bugs later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `self.` behind `humidityValue` when you were declaring the attributes in your `__init__`:

`humidityValue = humidityScale.get()` should be `self.humidityValue = humidityScale.get()`.

This is needed so that both objects created using your class AND functions inside the class (as you have witnessed) can self-reference attributes.

You probably will need to do the same changes to other variables in your `__init__` (eg `humidityScale`, `humidityLabel`).

---

In regards to why your function `set_humidity` doesn't work - you forgot to add `self` as the first parameter of the function, just like you've done with `get_humidity`

Comment: @pam Can you post the full trace-back error? Preferably in the main body of your question

Comment: It still gives me the same error
I even tried doing what you suggested and 
   def set_humidity(val):
      humidityValue = humidityScale.get()
But then it says that humidityScale is not defined for humidityScale.get()

Comment: @pam Check the bottom of my answer